ionic cordova and angular project ng-If not working
Project specs:
Ionic Cordova
Ionic 7
Angular 18.0.3
*ngIf not working.
page.html
<ion-segment [(ngModel)]="segment" (ionChange)="typeChange($event)">
    <ion-segment-button value="right">
        <ion-label>Right</ion-label>
    </ion-segment-button>
    <ion-segment-button value="missing">
        <ion-label>Missing</ion-label>
    </ion-segment-button>
    <ion-segment-button value="damaged">
        <ion-label>Damaged</ion-label>
    </ion-segment-button>
</ion-segment>

<div *ngIf="segment == 'right'">
    Right
  </div>

  <div *ngIf="segment == 'missing'">
    Missing
  </div>

  <div *ngIf="segment == 'damaged'">
    Damaged
  </div>


page.ts:

segment = "right";

typeChange(event) {
    console.log(this.segment);
}


Above is my code.
Expected output
Actual output
Please, help me find a solution.
Thank you

Please try the below code in page.ts:
segment: string = 'right';  // Default to 'right'
    
    typeChange(event: any) {
        this.segment = event.detail.value;  // Update segment value on change
        console.log(this.segment);  // Log for debugging
    }

Use the strict equality operator (===) instead of ==.
<ion-segment [(ngModel)]="segment" (ionChange)="typeChange($event)">
  <ion-segment-button value="right">
    <ion-label>Right</ion-label>
  </ion-segment-button>
  <ion-segment-button value="missing">
    <ion-label>Missing</ion-label>
  </ion-segment-button>
  <ion-segment-button value="damaged">
    <ion-label>Damaged</ion-label>
  </ion-segment-button>
</ion-segment>

<div *ngIf="segment === 'right'">
  Right
</div>

<div *ngIf="segment === 'missing'">
  Missing
</div>

<div *ngIf="segment === 'damaged'">
  Damaged
</div>


Thanks for replying. I tried that also. But, still it's not working.

@AnantPatel I have edited the above answer.please check now
